# Ruby: Variable variable / method call + security concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, variables, methods

So, this is a rails app but really more of a general ruby question:

I have a model with several scopes. For example:

```
Photo.recent
Photo.popular
Photo.featured
```

I have a "browse photos" view in my app where I want to be able to pass a single param and let the user specify a scope they want to view, ie:

```
example.com/photos/browse?view=recent
```

This gives me params[:view], and I need to attach that as a method call on Photo.

So my first question is, how can you do that kind of thing in Ruby?

Second, this could be a security risk if I can't constrain the input, if I just attach Photo.`whatever the user types in the url` then I'm at risk for a hacker saying `example.com/photos/browse?view=delete_all` That, obviously, is a bad idea.

So my second question is, how can I create a whitelist or something for what can be called -- or even better setup some kind of method that can accept the param from the URL safely and only return information if the user is requesting a valid named scope.

Lastly, I have some scopes that are only for admins. I have user abilities defined (using CanCan) so I can query `current_user.has_role?` to check if a user is authorized for anything, but is there a way to associate permissions with a scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH, unless you have a *lot* of these scopes, I would just hardcode them or create a hash mapping the url param values to lambdas

In the event that you do want to do exactly what you said, you could do something like:

```
whitelist = %w(
  recent
  popular
  featured
)

if whitelist.include? params[:view]
  photos = Photo.send params[:view].to_sym
end
```

See: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

**EDIT**: Perhaps try this?

```
if Photo.valid_scope_name? params[:view]
  photos = Photo.send params[:view].to_sym
end
```

It's a protected method, so you might have to use:

```
if Photo.send :valid_scope_name?, params[:view]
  photos = Photo.send params[:view].to_sym
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/valid_scope_name%3F

Comment: This looks workable, and I think the number of scopes is manageable. Out of curiosity do you have any idea how to do it without a manually-written whitelist?

Answer (score 1):

To send a method, use the [send](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) method :)

```
Photo.send(params[:view].to_sym)
```

However, you are 100% correct to assume this (might) be a security concern. Subsequently, you may want to do something like the following:

```
Photo.send(params[:view].to_sym) if %w(recent popular featured).include?(params[:view])
```

Comment: FYI the send method accepts strings too... no need for to_sym